# Access, query "LIKE" with Mask

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an Access mask where the user inputs a Value and I would like to extract results that contain the specified value.

I tried to write something like:

```
SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3
FROM Table
WHERE Table.Field1 LIKE '*[Forms]![myForm]![Value]*';
```

But I do not know how to pass to the LIKE expression a dynamic variable.
In particular, I do not know how to express correctly this part `LIKE '*[Forms]![myForm]![Value]*'`. I guess it should be something like `LIKE '*'+[Forms]![myForm]![Value]+'*'` but I do not know how to concatenate.

Thanks

Comment: You need to explain what `[Forms]![myForm]![Value]` is meant to represent. Do you want to replace that text with the value of something in `myForm`?

Comment: We need more information I'm afraid, as 'does not work' is not very helpful.  Can you provide an example of the data you're accessing, what you want in the result, and what you're getting?

Comment: @underscore_d exactly, that is a variable which is taken by the mask. I do not know how to concatenate the asterisks * and the variable.

Comment: Did you try just using standard string concatenation with the `&` operator? e.g. `"*" & Forms!myForm!Value & "*"`? Or maybe you need to use `+`... I've not used MS Access with forms, just queries.

Comment: @underscore_d thanks. That was exactly the point, I did not know how to concatenate in Access. `&` worked. Thanks a lot

Comment: Note that you can concatenate using `+`. It's just unconventional in MS Access. Using `& ` to concatenate is more usual and more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a textbox on your form and you want to query using that value.
As it is your SQL is trying to get a value from the form rather than a value from a control on the form.
Unless your control is called `Value` in which case you've got a whole raft of other problems as that's a reserved word that's used all over the place.

```
PARAMETERS Forms!myForm!myTextBox Text ( 255 );
SELECT Field1, Field2, FIeld3
FROM Table
WHERE Field1 LIKE '*' & Forms!myForm!myTextBox & '*'
```